# Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack by Checkmarx scanner for visualforce component,

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, checkmarx, xss

[image]I am Using visualforce component for insert and updating child record. this component is reusable for multiple objects, like account, contact, etc., as like we can use this. I am doing DML inside a component. this component just receives a parentId through attribute, and we need to perform adding rows (childRecords) and need to save. Please suggest me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi DSuresh, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post the code for your component and any related controller, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: @Dupada DS Have you fixed this? If so, please add the solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of another question even though this one came first — they clearly relate to the same error, but the other includes some more information and has what I believe to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving parentId through the attribute then before using parentId in the DML, use `String.escapeSingleQuotes(parentId)` and then use it in the DML.

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Since you have not shared the code, it is just a guess.